# How to add initialVisibleMonth in DayPickerSingleDateController in react-dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, calendar, react-dates

```
      <DayPickerSingleDateController
        numberOfMonths={1}
        keepOpenOnDateSelect={true}
        dayPickerNavigationInlineStyles={{ color: 'red' }}
        onDateChange={handleSinglePickerDateChange}
        focused={false}            
        date={moment(clickedDate)}
        onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => {
          console.log('focus change of DayPickerSingleDateController');
        }}
        initialVisibleMonth={() => moment(new Date('01-08-2023'))}
        isDayBlocked={getBlockedDay}
        isDayHighlighted={getHighlightedDay}
      />
```

In above, I'm trying to set initialVisible month of calendar to september.
Is there any syntax error I'm doing here or something is buggy here?

Please help if anyone know the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's syntax error, change the line from `initialVisibleMonth={() => moment(new Date('01-08-2023'))}`
to
`initialVisibleMonth={ moment(new Date('01-08-2023')}`

Comment: So you mean it expects a object, but in their github, initialVisibleMonth type mention as a PropTypes.func
[link](https://github.com/react-dates/react-dates/blob/master/examples/DayPickerSingleDateControllerWrapper.jsx)

you can test it here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-cache-cj4z34?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right

Comment: Use the below format `moment('25/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`